# Something wrong with java multiclient chat server. Clients are unable to recieve messages?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, server, client

The clients are not able to communicate with each other. Only the server receives all the messages. The first client is only able to receive messages from the server. Please help!

Below are the server and client codes. As you can see below we have used socket connection and are implementing threads. We have used threads for printing multiple lines. The problem lies in the part of accepting connections. Even though connections are being accepted we cannot communicate with the clients.

```
    /*Server Code*/
    package gossipserver;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    public class GossipServer
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    try{
    ServerSocket sersock = new ServerSocket(4778);    //opening of a socket
    System.out.println("Server ready");
    boolean listeningSocket = true;
    while(listeningSocket){
    Socket sock = sersock.accept( );  
   System.out.println("Connection received from client on  port "+sock.getPort());
  //sock.getport() to return port number of client
  //create two threads to send and receive
  ReceiveThread ReadThread = new ReceiveThread(sock);
  Thread thread1 = new Thread(ReadThread);
  thread1.start();
  SendThread WriteThread = new SendThread(sock);
  Thread thread2 = new Thread(WriteThread);
  thread2.start();
  MClient thread3 = new MClient (sock);
  thread3.start();
  }
  sersock.close();        
  }  
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      System.out.println("Error" +e);
  }
 }
 }

    class ReceiveThread implements Runnable     //creating class thread as runnable
    {
Socket clientSocket=null;
BufferedReader keyRead = null;  // reading from keyboard (keyRead  object)
public ReceiveThread(Socket clientSocket)
{
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
}//end constructor
public void run() {
    try{    
    keyRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            //get inputstream
    String receiveMessage;
    while(true){
    while((receiveMessage = keyRead.readLine())!= null){
          //assign message from client to receiveMessage
        if(receiveMessage.equals("Quit"))
        {
            break;//break to close socket if Quit
        }
        System.out.println("Client"+"("+clientSocket.getPort()+"):"+receiveMessage);
            //print the message from client
    }
    this.clientSocket.close();
}
}
catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}
       }//end run
           }//end class ReceiveThread

    class SendThread implements Runnable
    {
   PrintWriter pwrite;
Socket clientSock = null;

public SendThread(Socket clientSock)
{
    this.clientSock = clientSock;
}
public void run() {
    try{
    pwrite = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(this.clientSock.getOutputStream()));
            //get outputstream
    System.out.println("Press enter to send.");
    while(true)
    {
        String sendMessage = null;
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                    //get userinput         
        sendMessage = input.readLine();//get message to send to client
        pwrite.println(sendMessage);//send message to client with PrintWriter
        pwrite.flush();//flush the PrintWriter

    }//end while
    }
    catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex.getMessage());}   
}//end run
    }//end class SendThread

     class MClient extends Thread 
     {
    private Socket socket = null;
    public MClient (Socket socket) {
    super("MClient");         //invoking overridden method through the use of the keyword super
    socket = socket;
}
public void run(){
         //Read input and process
    }
          //implement methods
} 






    /*Client Code*/
    package client;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    public class Client
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
     {
       try
      {
     Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4778);   //opening of a socket
     System.out.println("Client is connected to server. Ready to chat");
     //create two threads to send and receive
     SendThread WriteThread = new SendThread(sock);
     Thread thread1 = new Thread(WriteThread);
     thread1.start();
     ReceiveThread ReadThread = new ReceiveThread(sock);
     Thread thread2 =new Thread(ReadThread);
     thread2.start();
      }
 catch(Exception e)
      {
          System.out.println("Error" + e);
      }
  }
}

class ReceiveThread implements Runnable    //creating class thread as runnable
{
    Socket sock=null;
    BufferedReader keyread=null;    // reading from keyboard (keyRead object)
    public ReceiveThread(Socket sock) {
        this.sock = sock;
    }//end constructor
    public void run() {
    try{
    keyread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.sock.getInputStream()));
            //get inputstream
        String receiveMessage = null;
        while((receiveMessage = keyread.readLine())!= null)
        {
            System.out.println("Server: " + receiveMessage);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
         }//end run
}//end class ReceiveThread

class SendThread implements Runnable
{
    Socket sock=null;
    PrintWriter pwrite=null;
    BufferedReader receiveRead=null;

    public SendThread(Socket sock)
    {
        this.sock = sock;
    }//end constructor
    public void run(){
        try{
        if(sock.isConnected())
        {
    System.out.println("Client connected to server on port "+sock.getPort());
            //sock.getport() to return port number of server
    this.pwrite = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
            //get outputstream
        System.out.println("Press enter to send. Type 'Quit' to quit chat");
        while(true){
            receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String sendMessage=null;
            sendMessage = receiveRead.readLine();
            this.pwrite.println(sendMessage);
            this.pwrite.flush();
            if(sendMessage.equals("Quit"))
            break;
            }//end while
        sock.close();}}catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
        }//end run method
}//end class SendThread
```